# Spring JDBCTemplate returning null with Oracle LISTAGG Query

Tags: java, mysql, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

```
private List<String> getExcludes(String eventId){
    String sql = "select LISTAGG(messageSubject, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY messageSubject) AS excludes from exclude where eventid = ?";
    String excludes = (String) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {eventId}, String.class);
    if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(excludes)){
        return Arrays.asList(excludes.split(","));
    }
    return null;
}
```

when running above sql via jdbctemplate.queryForObject, I'm getting null results, but when I'm running same query in database, I'm getting comma separated results as - TEMP-SUBJECT-36,TEMP-SUBJECT-37,TEMP-SUBJECT-38, why jdbc template query returning null, what I'm doing wrong here, please help?

Comment: Is the `eventId` String compatible with the `eventid` database column type?

Comment: yes, database column type is varchar, so there is no exception or compatibility issue.

Comment: Perhaps enable trace logging or download the Spring source and step through to see the exact query the PreparedStatement is executing.